# Last observation of the previous group

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to know, if I have data that I can group by a variable, how can I get the last observation of the previous group?

I have the following data:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), b=sample.int(21))
```

I would like to create a new data.table that has the group ID and the difference between the last observation of the group from the last observation of the previous group. So that from the above I'd get:

```
   a  c
1: 1 NA
2: 2  9
3: 3  1
4: 4 -8
5: 5  5
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please do use `set.seed` to make this reproducible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'a', get the `last` element of 'b', then take the `lag` of 'c' by `shift`ing

```
dt[, .(c = last(b)), a][,  c:= shift(c)][]
```

Comment: This way should be efficient since glast (part of GForce) will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
dt[, c := b * (1:.N == .N), by = a] ## get last row within the group
dt <- dt[b == c] ## filter data.table to get rows of interest
dt[, c := shift(c, type = "lag") - c][] ## getting difference using shift with lag argument

#   a  b  c
#1: 1 11 NA
#2: 2 10 NA
#3: 3 18  9
#4: 4 19 -7
#5: 5 12 -8
```

## data

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5,5), b=sample.int(21))
```